# CoreData : error return nil when trying to fetch

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to fetch data I've previously saved but things don't go as expected. When I try to print a result, I get the following error :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-02-26 15:32:32.596867 Money Manager[2047:475120] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I couldn't find any answer that worked for me ...

Here is the code when I try to fetch :

```
func getExpensesData() {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Activity> = Activity.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as [Activity]
        activities = results
        for activity in activities {
            // I get the error I mentionned just the line below
            print(activity.title!)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

where Activity is an entity.

Here is also the code when I save the data :

```
func saveNewContent() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Activity", in: context)!
    let newActivity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context) as! Activity

    if checkFieldsAreValid() {
        newActivity.isExpense = expenseBenefitSwitch.isOn
        newActivity.isRecurrent = recurrentSwitch.isOn
        newActivity.amount = amountView.text
        newActivity.title = titleView.text
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for some mistakes I could have made, it's my first post here. Please let me know if you need other pieces of code.

Thanks in advance !!

**Update #1:**

After running several other tests, I got that the data I try to save, that is **newActivity**, looks empty before being saved ...

When I put a breakpoint right before

```
try context.save()
```

here is what I get :
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag20G.png)

**Update #2 :**

After searching even deeper, I found out that the problem seems to be linked with CoreData faulting, as the error occurs when I try to get one of the object's attribute.

When I print one of the object fetched, I get this :

```
<Activity: 0x170284dd0> (entity: Activity; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://
68148348-928B-43BE-901C-2073ABFA46EF/Activity/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

Here is the code I use when I try to get the attribute (used in a custom subclass of UITableViewCell) :

```
func initialize(withContent activity: Activity) {
    print(activity)
    titleLabel.text = (activity.value(forKey: "title") as! String)
}
```

Comment: Please provide the response, you might be missing the structure, you need to parse data correctly. Check your response structure or provide me.

Comment: Error defines, activity is nil and it is trying to access title, and it is causing the fatal error.

Comment: Did you try deleting your app and trying again?  You may have an `Activity` entity in your database that was created before you added the core to make sure to only insert `Activity` entities with a non-nil title.

Comment: @Ren I updated the post

Comment: @JonRose I did several times : no problem when I run it for the first time (obviously) but the error happen when I try to save something new :/

Comment: You're doing a forced unwrap with `as! String` - your title might be `nil` and that causes a crash. It may be that you never specified a title in one of your objects.

Comment: can you share the code from `checkFieldsAreValid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after investing my app deeper and deeper, I found out that the error wasn't raised because of CoreData but because of a custom UITableViewCell I forgot to initialise correctly ... Because of that, when I tried to do :

```
textLabel.text = activity.title
```

it raised the error because of the UILabel, not the activity...

Thank you very much for your help, I take note of your advices !

Comment: Cool ! You found the solution.